# Paramiko, appending file on SSH server

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

I'm writing a class which communicates with a text file on a remote SSH server (sitting on a windows machine) using the paramiko library. I have the following line in my python app (sitting on a linux machine) which should establish a connection for appending a file;

```
file(pollFile, mode='a', bufsize=1)
```

But how do I actually go about interacting with this file I've established a conneciton with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object returned from the `file` call is a [`paramiko.SFTPFile`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SFTPFile-class.html) handle, which can be interacted with using [`write`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.BufferedFile-class.html#write), [`writelines`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.BufferedFile-class.html#writelines) e.g.

```
data = "Hello World"
file_hande = sftp_client.file(pollFile, mode='a', bufsize=1)
file_handle.write(data)
file_handle.flush()
file_handle.close()
```